# Copy webpage as it is rendered, regardless of underlaying source

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

So I have this webpage that I want to copy to a word document. It's an installation guide and we want to use that but add comments relating to how we installed the program in our environment.

Simple problem. Just copy and paste, right? Wrong.

Problem is, this specific webpage is built up of `<div ..>` tags, where a couple of checkboxes enable/disable them relating to your choices. So I check the box that marks an installation in Linux, and all div tags relating to that installation option are shown.

Example from the source:

`<div class="forWindows forAIX forLinux forZLinux forPLinux forSolaris">...</div>`

`<div class="forJTS"> ... </div>`

`<div class="forCCM"> ... </div>`

This means, that whenever I copy and paste a part of the webpage I get all the content, regardless of what I actually see on the screen. What I want is to just copy the webpage as I see it on the screen.

I've tried to copy from Internet Explorer and Firefox both to MS Word and to a basic text editor with the same results.

I want the result to be text so I can edit it, so screenshots or exporting to PDF won't work.

I could save the source HTML, remove the tags that dont apply and open the local html file, except that it's quite alot of work. Also the page seems to rely heavily on scripts on the serverside, so I guess that may cause some issues.

Ideally I'd like to preserve the formatting as it is shown aswell.

To reproduce the issue:

1. Go to the IBM's interactive guide for [installing Rational Team Concert](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/roadmap_form.html).
2. Select any choices, but to verify step 5-6 below, choose Linux as OS.
3. Click "Get your interactions"
4. Copy/paste a part of the webpage and compare the pasted version with what is seen in the browser.
5. Go to Step 3, "set up the database" in the guide. Copy all the content between "What to do next" in the previous step to the end of the heading in step 3. All in all, about 6 lines.
6. Paste in a texteditor, you should now see text that only relates to zOS and IBMi operating systems.

Comment: It seems to work for me. I chose a bunch of options. Copy and pasted it to word and it looks the same in firefox as in word. I checked the frame source and can indeed see a lot of other content for other platforms but don't see it in my word document. You could always try to run some javascript against it to find everything hidden and actually remove it from the dom.

Comment: @Chris Intresting, perhaps you chose to many options? If you select them all, everything will be shown. I've update the steps to show what I have been coping to see the issue.

Comment: I chose one option from each selection and could see there was definitely hidden markup that wasn't displaying. In general I would expect content with `display: none` not to be copied when copying HTML. Following your more detailed steps I still get just what I had on screen. I checked the beginning of section 4 whose first paragraph is just "forDerby" and is a single sentence and this doesn't appear on copying content either. If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/Q8ePx/ and copy the text and paste it elsewhere do you get the hidden text there?

Comment: @Chris If I paste the JSFiddle in my EditPlus editor, I see the hidden text, but not in MS Word. I retried to copy the text from the guide to word, but the hidden text was pasted. 
Could this be related to the browser perhaps? I've tried using IE 8.0 and FF 3.6. I'll try again from home where I'm using Chrome

Comment: ah yes. If I use IE8 I get the same thing. I'm using FF 14.0.1 and its doing the right thing. You might want to upgrade your firefox and see if that helps.

Comment: @Chris Bingo. That did it, chrome worked. Post it as a proper reply and Ill give you the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the behaviour on copy and pasting is undefined. Some browsers will copy ignoring the styling that hides stuff and others will copy including styles (ie some will include hidden text and others will not).

A rough summary of browsers seems to be:

- IE - copies hidden text on IE8 and presumably older, no idea about newer.
- FF - newer versions will not copy hidden text, older versions it seems will. Unknown where the cutoff is but it seems to be somewhere between version 3 and version 14. :)
- Chrome - my current version (19.0.1084.52) will copy just the visible text. Untested on any other version.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply screenshot the page and use a simple graphics editing program to crop the image and add annotations.

To screenshot a page, press Print screen (probably shorted as PrtScn on your keyboard).  That copies the screenshot into memory.
 Now, in your graphics editing program or even word processor, click paste (or press ctrl-v).  The screenshot will appear.  Crop and add annotations as per your desire.

Comment: Copying and pasting the contents will be horrible, you should absolutely use this approach.

Comment: Thanks, but that would make it alot more difficult to add text and to maintain. If I want to change/add/remove a word/sentence in the middle of a paragraph, it will be quite problematic. I think editing the source and removing the text that doesnt apply would be better in that case.

Comment: @SLC If you are referring to formatting; If I paste to an editor that understands HTML (such as Word) most of the formatting will actually be kept the same.

Comment: How will having to annotate approximately 25 pages of documentation using a graphic editor be in any way better, not to mention the faff of having to take all those screenshots and edit them down to what you want. And won't it make searching the document kind of hard?

Answer (score 0):

Write a bookmarklet that concatenates #text nodes together but only when the parent element has a computed-style where `display != none` and `visiblity != hidden`.

Comment: Wouldn't concatenating text nodes just give you one massive unformatted block of text?